# boost unordered_map reverse foreach

Tags: c++, boost, iteration, reverse, unordered-map

I have found, that BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH doesn't work in the same way as BOOST_FOREACH.

My code:

```
#include <boost\unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost\foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;

int main()
{
    map MyMap;

    MyMap["two"] = 2;
    MyMap["three"] = 3;
    MyMap["one"] = 1;

    std::cout << MyMap["one"] << MyMap["two"] << MyMap["three"] << std::endl;

    BOOST_FOREACH (map::value_type value, MyMap)
    {
        std::cout << value.second;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but also I want to use reverse iteration.
So I add:

```
BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH (map::value_type value, MyMap)
{
    std::cout << value.second;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

After this it doesn't compile, does anyone could tell how to use reverse foreach on unordered map.

Compiler gives:

```
1>c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\iterator\reverse_iterator.hpp(45): error C2675: unary '--' : 'boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator<NodePointer,Value>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>          with
1>          [
1>              NodePointer=boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<std::pair<const std::string,int>> *,
1>              Value=std::pair<const std::string,int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\iterator\reverse_iterator.hpp(45) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::reverse_iterator<Iterator>::increment(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Iterator=boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<std::pair<const std::string,int>> *,std::pair<const std::string,int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp(520) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::reverse_iterator<Iterator>::increment(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Iterator=boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<std::pair<const std::string,int>> *,std::pair<const std::string,int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\foreach.hpp(266) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::reverse_iterator<Iterator>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Iterator=boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<std::pair<const std::string,int>> *,std::pair<const std::string,int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\t3\documents\projects\boost unorderedmap test\boost unorderedmap test\main.cpp(25) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::reverse_iterator<boost::unordered::iterator_detail::iterator<boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<std::pair<const std::string,int>> *,std::pair<const std::string,int>>>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What error message does the compiler give you when it fails compiling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you do not iterate over an `unordered_map` in reverse.

`unordered_map` provides no order.  Thus, iterating over the container results in an arbitrary order.  If it was possible to iterate over it in reverse, it would produce an equally arbitrary order.  If an application needs to iterate over an `unordered_map` in reverse, then the application is dependent on the order, and cannot safely use an `unordered_map`.  As such, alternative container types should be considered.  For example:

- If insertion order is important and look-ups never occur, then use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>`
- If insertion order is important, and look-ups do occur, then consider [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

To expand upon the compiler error, Boost.ForEach tries to obtain an rbegin and rend iterator.  In the end, Boost.ForEach will try to adapt *Sequence::iterator* with [`boost::reverse_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/reverse_iterator.html#reverse-iterator-requirements), requiring the adapted iterator be a *bidirectional iterator*.  While the [`boost::unordered_map::iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#boost.unordered_map.iterator) iterator type is implementation defined, it must at least be a *forward iterator*.  Thus, when the `reverse_iterator` is incremented, it decrements the underlying iterator, resulting in the compiler error, as *Sequence::iterator* does not provide a unary decrement operator (`--`).

Comment: What Tanner said. `BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH` needs at least a bidirectional iterator. `boost::unordered_map::iterator` is only a forward iterator. And you can't expact any particular ordering anyway given the very nature of an _unordered_ container. (Aside: I'm the author of `BOOST_FOREACH`. Please stop using it. Use C++11's range-based for loop instead.)